# Are there any prepaid cards that can be used in Russia?

Tags: russia, payment-cards, forex-cards

Are there any prepaid cards that can be used in any transaction online in Russia?
If so, where do I buy them?

Comment: There are many kinds of cards which can be prepaid, such as giftcards and cards used as tickets for many transit systems. But am I right in assuming you mean the cards also known as "travel cards", "travel money cards", and "forex cards"?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know anything about prepaid cards before this question, but it looks like the prepaid cards can be a `Visa` or `Mastercard` type, which both are being used in Russia widely.

So, if you do bring some of such prepaid cards in Russia, you probably be good with payments made in places accepting two mentioned payment systems. As all over the world, you can see some stickers on entrance or near the cashier about what types of cards are accepted.

In general people in Russia do not understand the difference between those system, and call them just a "cards" (карточки, kartochkye). Usually some big bank do provide the service for a card machine, and they do not have problems with either system, but it really depends on city, place and time you try to do a purchase.

As for **online** transactions, the payment agent usually **do not support** cards from other countries rather than Russia, so you need to visit a bank to buy such card. For example, Russian biggest bank "Sberbank" [offers such cards for sale in Moscow and Saint Petersburg](http://www.sberbank.ru/en/individualclients/cards/giftcards/visaprepaidcard):

> You can purchase a prepaid card in Euroset outlets located at: *32 Zolotorozhsky Val, Moscow*, and *36/40 Sredniy Vasilyevskiy Ostrov Avenue, Vasilyevskiy Island, Saint Petersburg*

**Update**: The prepaid cards you're talking about aren't much popular in Russia yet, but you still can try to investigate this: [Russian Standard Bank' cards](https://www.rsb.ru/cards/prepaid/mastercard/) (also they are related with [this website](https://www.daricard.ru/catalog/), but I can't find any information about it's real usage experience); [GazProm Bank' cards](http://www.gazprombank.ru/personal/bank_cards/cards/242533/) (you can buy them in bank's branches); and, as expected, [SberBank is providing some virtual cards too](https://moneypolo.com/int-en/products/prepaid-cards/), and it looks like they can be bought online.

Comment: If ordered a prepaid card on a bank still I need to wait for almost a week ?

Comment: In U.S there's a prepaid card like ONE Vanilla, you can find that in all store's or gas station especially on Walmart, And you can avail that and activate it by your own, this is the method I need right now so, I don't need to go in bank to wait for almost one week. by the way thanks for a top answer

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: "payment agent usually do not support cards from other countries rather than Russia" do you mean prepaid cards here? Because I'm pretty sure you can pay online in Russia with (named) foreign cards.

Comment: Some payment agents may not accept foreigh cards. I had issues with pizza delivery and railway tickets. That were named Visa and MasterCard.

Comment: So where can I but a Visa or MasterCard Gift Cards That can be able for online transaction, if in case I don't want to order that kind of card online, because I need to wait for almost a week If I ordered online.

Comment: I've provided some links for you already

Answer (score 0):

One point more - only 2 card transactions aviable for "unnamed cards"

- Cashless payment for goods and services both in Russia and abroad
- Online payment for goods and services